# "sqlcmd.exe -S Instance USE ..." work in command line, but I can't move it to c # process

Tags: c#, command-line

I am trying move this command to C# Process:

```
SQLCMD.EXE -S InstanceName
USE [master]
GO
CREATE DATABASE [Ek] ON
( FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL 
Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Ek_Primary.mdf' ),
( FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL 
Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Ek_Primary.ldf' )
FOR ATTACH ;
GO
EXIT
```

I have:

```
try
{
     Process p = CreateProcess();
     p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE";
     p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-S InstanceName" + "\n" +
     "USE [master]" + "\n" +
     "GO" + "\n" +
     "CREATE DATABASE [Ek] ON" + "\n" +
     "( FILENAME = N'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\\MSSQL\\DATA\\Ek_Primary.mdf' )," + "\n" +
     "( FILENAME = N'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\\MSSQL\\DATA\\Ek_Primary.ldf' )" + "\n" +
     "FOR ATTACH ;" + "\n" +
     "GO" + "\n" +
     "EXIT" + "\n";
     Console.WriteLine(p.StartInfo.Arguments);
     p.Start();
     var output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
     var err = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
     Console.WriteLine("O: " + output);
     Console.WriteLine("E: " + err);
}
catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e.Message); ; }
```

It return err = Unexpected argument. Enter '-?' for help.

I was trying set FileName on cmd.exe and move path to Arguments. But it waits forever for a response and does not exit p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd ();

I was trying send each line of code individually, but also without success.

And I trying with /C on start p.StartInfo.Argument but it does not change anything.

Comment: as I wrote in the comment to your previous(similar, deleted) question sql query need to be preceded with ritgh switch .. check switch name qith `sqlcmd /?` ... moreover with multiline sql statement it is better tu write it in file and pase path to shis file to sqlcmd

Comment: @Selvin Thanks that you wanted to write it again, I can not find an example of how to do what you wrote, so I added a new question to make it understandable to a larger number of people and maybe someone else would suggest something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Selvin suggestion. I made it by:

```
string sqlConnectionString = @"Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=InstanceName";
string script = File.ReadAllText(@"../../sql.sql");
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);
Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn));
server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
```

where in sql.sql I added all my sql line.